# NSToolbarButtonItem does not appear as defined

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I created a custom toolbar item. I've resized it to the size I want it to appear. However, when I run my application, it still stays in a rectangular shape as opposed to take a more square one:
[image]

Comment: You have only one item in default items, so one will be shown!!!

Comment: I know, I want the button "Sélectionner" to be shaped as it is shown in default not as it is in a rectangular way

Comment: Check for the image type, Axes independence, none etc. If none works better to go with a combination of NSButton and label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the minimum and maximum size to 0 did it. However, it will not be represented in XCode but will be the proper size once the application is launched. Weird bug !